# Media queries not working in smartphone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am having strange issue. I completed a website and was using screenfly from quirktools to see how it would appear on tablets and smartphones..... it look fine

When I viewed the site on a smart phone or tablet in real, it was showing the site in desktop version ... media queries are not working ... I tried chrome, firefox, opera all on my phone but non of them is showing my site in mobile version.

Friends can you tell me what can possible be wrong ?

I am using simple media queries in my css file

Comment: We all are humans here, we need some code, or examples, so please provide them, else no one will solve the issues.

Comment: media-queries are working on most smartphone (all that i know), so maybe show the queries, so someone can tell you what you did wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you set a meta tag for the viewport? Something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this meta tag in between

```
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also Try out this meta tag which will make your media Query work on all size of devices

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Thanks